# Datagrid not rendering column from linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datagrid, northwind

I am using northwind database and try to return product table using linq to sql. below pasted my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DemoDataContext dbContext = new DemoDataContext();
            var lyncQuery = from product in dbContext.Products
                            where product.CategoryID == 2
                            orderby product.UnitPrice descending
                            select product;
            ProductDataGrid.DataSource = lyncQuery;
            Response.Write(lyncQuery.ToString());
            ProductDataGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

i verified lyncquery returns all the columns by printing that in response.write, when i debug also i am seeing all the columns value in lyncquery but when i am binding that with datagrid  i am seeing only productid, productname, discontinued,quantityperunit as below.

[image]

even i tried returning specific columns using below in select clause,
select new { product.ProductID, product.ProductName, product.CategoryID, product.SupplierID, product.Discontinued, product.UnitPrice, product.QuantityPerUnit };

but still i am seeing only those 4 columns

any lead can help me in resolve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check this entry :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393223/binding-linq-query-to-datagridview?answertab=active#tab-top I think it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you Autogenerating Columns in the GRIDVIEW or you have specified the columns to be shown in the gridview.
There may be possibility that you are only displaying these 4 columns.
Can you please Add your HTML page code also.

Comment: I am auto generating and not specifying anything in my html.. attached the code below,  
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DataGrid ID="ProductDataGrid" runat="server" ></asp:DataGrid>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

I think you had to place this data into DataTable And then to provide it to the gridView source then may it will work.